# Keras - using embedding with multiple categorical variables

Tags: keras, embedding

If I understand the concept of embedding matrices correctly, they exist to provide a more efficient way to encode categorical variables than by using one hot encoding. It seems that if you have multiple categorical variables as inputs to a Keras model, you need to use a separate embedding matrix for each categorical variable. However, I can't find a way to use embedding with multiple categorical variables using the Embedding class provided by Keras. The example in the documentation shows only how to use embedding when the input to the model is a single categorical variable. Can somebody please provide a working example of how to use embedding with Keras when the input consists of multiple categorical variables, and possibly other variables for which embedding is not used (for example, continuous variables)?

Answer (score 2):

For each categorical variable, you can have separate embedding. Hope the below code helps.

```
    inputss = []
    embeddings = []
    for c in self.categorical_vars:
        inputs = Input(shape=(1,),name='input_sparse_'+c)
        #no_of_unique_cat  = data_lr[categorical_var].nunique()
        embedding_size = min(np.ceil((no_of_unique_cat)/2), 50 )
        embedding_size = int(embedding_size)
        embedding = Embedding(no_of_unique_cat+1, embedding_size, input_length = 1)(inputs)
        embedding = Reshape(target_shape=(embedding_size,))(embedding)
        inputss.append(inputs)
        embeddings.append(embedding)
    input_numeric = Input(shape=(1,),name='input_constinuous')
    embedding_numeric = Dense(16)(input_numeric)
    inputss.append(input_numeric)
    embeddings.append(embedding_numeric)

    x = Concatenate()(embeddings)

    x = Dense(10, activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(.15)(x)
    out_control = Dense(output_shape)(x)
```

Comment: But then, how do you distinguish between an embedding in one variable and in another variable if their embedded outcome is the same?  Can you tell keras to use different embeddings?